# Plotly JS: Animate pie chart

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

It is possible to realize a smooth animation when changing the pie chart data? I did something similar before with **scatter plots**, **indicators** and **bar charts**, but my solution does not work for pie charts.

So, is a smooth animation possible with plotly js? Are pie charts not supported yet?

**Codepen example:** https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/yLaEBJr

**Draw chart:**

```
function drawChart() {
  generateRandomValues();
  let graph = document.querySelector('#graph');
  let plotWidth = graph.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let plotHeight = graph.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  let data = [{
    type: "pie",
    values: VALUES,
    labels: LABELS,
    textinfo: 'percent',
    automargin: true,
  }];
  let layout = {
    paper_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    width: plotWidth,
    height: plotHeight,
    margin: { "t": 0, "b": 0, "l": 0, "r": 0 },
    showlegend: true,
  }
  Plotly.newPlot(graph.id, data, layout, { displaylogo: false, responsive: true, staticPlot: true });
 }
```

**Animate chart:**

```
function updateChart(){
  generateRandomValues();
  Plotly.animate('graph', {
        data: [
            {
                y: VALUES,
                x: LABELS,
            }
        ],
        traces: [0]
    },
        {
            transition: {
                duration: 750, easing: 'cubic-in-out'
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Has the documentation's says (updated instantaneously)

> Currently, only scatter traces may be smoothly transitioned from one
> state to the next. Other traces are compatible with frames and
> animations but will be updated instantaneously.

https://plotly.com/javascript/animations/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Link-only answers are frowned upon on this website.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using tween.js. This smoothly animates the pull parameter of a pie chart, on hover.

```js
var data = [{
  values: [19, 26, 55],
  labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
  pull: [0, 0, 0],
  type: 'pie',
  automargin: true
}];

var layout = {
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%"
};

var plot = document.getElementById('plot')
Plotly.newPlot(plot, data, layout);

window.tween = null;

function tween_function(d, from=0, to=0.5) {
  var tweenValue = {pull: from}
  window.tween = new TWEEN.Tween(tweenValue, false)
  .to({pull: to}, 300)
  .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut)
  .onUpdate(() => {
    var pull = [0,0,0]
    pull[d.pointNumber] = tweenValue.pull
    d.data.pull = pull
    Plotly.restyle(plot, {
      marker: {
        pull: pull
      }
    });
  }).start()
}

function animate(time) {
  if (window.tween) {
      window.tween.update(time)
  }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()

plot.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
  //if (tween && tween.isPlaying()) return
  var d = data.points[0]
  tween_function(d)
});

plot.on('plotly_unhover', function(data) {
  if (tween && tween.isPlaying()) return
  var d = data.points[0]
  tween_function(d, 0.5, 0)
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/neonninja/pen/Bavwwqy